# Extract jpg name from a url using R

Tags: r, url, jpeg

someone could help me, this is my problem:
I have a list of urls in a tbl and I have to extract the jpg nane.
this is the url
https://content_xxx.xxx.com/vp/969ffffff61/5C55ABEB/t51.2ff5-15/e35/13643048_612108275661958_805860992_n.jpg?ff_cache_key=fffffQ%3ff%3D.2
and this one the part to extract 
13643048_612108275661958_805860992_n
thanks for helps

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Before you ask a question, there is an expectation that you show some effort to solve a specific problem. Stack Overflow is not a free code writing or resource discovery service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googling for "R parse URL" could have saved you from typing ~400 keystrokes (tho I expect the URL was pasted).

In any event, you want to process a vector of these things, so there's a better way. In fact there are multiple ways to do this URL path extraction in R. Here are 3:

```
library(stringi)
library(urltools)
library(httr)
library(XML)
library(dplyr)
```

We'll generate 100 unique URLs that fit the same Instagram pattern (NOTE: scraping instagram is a violation of their ToS & controlled by robots.txt. If your URLs did not come from the Instagram API, please let me know so I can delete this answer as I don't help content thieves).

```
set.seed(0)

paste(
  "https://content_xxx.xxx.com/vp/969ffffff61/5C55ABEB/t51.2ff5-15/e35/13643048_612108275661958_805860992_n.jpg?ff_cache_key=fffffQ%3ff%3D.2",
  stri_rand_strings(100, 8, "[0-9]"), "_",
  stri_rand_strings(100, 15, "[0-9]"), "_",
  stri_rand_strings(100, 9, "[0-9]"), "_",
  stri_rand_strings(100, 1, "[a-z]"),
  ".jpg?ff_cache_key=MTMwOTE4NjEyMzc1OTAzOTc2NQ%3D%3D.2",
  sep=""
) -> img_urls

head(img_urls)
## [1] "https://content_xxx.xxx.com/vp/969ffffff61/5C55ABEB/t51.2ff5-15/e35/13643048_612108275661958_805860992_n.jpg?ff_cache_key=fffffQ%3ff%3D.2"
## [2] "https://https://content_xxx.xxx.com/vp/969b7087cc97408ccee167d473388761/5C55ABEB/t51.2885-15/e35/66021637_359927357880233_471353444_q.jpg?ff_cache_key=MTMwOTE4NjEyMzc1OTAzOTc2NQ%3D%3D.2"
## [3] "https://https://content_xxx.xxx.com/vp/969b7087cc97408ccee167d473388761/5C55ABEB/t51.2885-15/e35/47937926_769874508959124_426288550_z.jpg?ff_cache_key=MTMwOTE4NjEyMzc1OTAzOTc2NQ%3D%3D.2"
## [4] "https://https://content_xxx.xxx.com/vp/vp/969b7087cc97408ccee167d473388761/5C55ABEB/t51.2885-15/e35/12303834_440673970920272_460810703_n.jpg?ff_cache_key=MTMwOTE4NjEyMzc1OTAzOTc2NQ%3D%3D.2"
## [5] "https://https://content_xxx.xxx.com/vp/969b7087cc97408ccee167d473388761/5C55ABEB/t51.2885-15/e35/54186717_202600346704982_713363439_y.jpg?ff_cache_key=MTMwOTE4NjEyMzc1OTAzOTc2NQ%3D%3D.2"
## [6] "https://https://content_xxx.xxx.com/vp/969b7087cc97408ccee167d473388761/5C55ABEB/t51.2885-15/e35/48675570_402479399847865_689787883_e.jpg?ff_cache_key=MTMwOTE4NjEyMzc1OTAzOTc2NQ%3D%3D.2"
```

Now, let's try to parse those URLs:

```
invisible(urltools::url_parse(img_urls))

invisible(httr::parse_url(img_urls))
## Error in httr::parse_url(img_urls): length(url) == 1 is not TRUE
```

DOH! `httr` can't do it.

```
invisible(XML::parseURI(img_urls))
## Error in if (is.na(uri)) return(structure(as.character(uri), class = "URI")): the condition has length > 1
```

DOH! `XML` can't do it either.

That means we need to use an `sapply()` crutch for `httr` and `XML` to get the path component (you can run `basename()` on any resultant vector as Konrad showed):

```
data_frame(
  urltools = urltools::url_parse(img_urls)$path,
  httr = sapply(img_urls, function(URL) httr::parse_url(URL)$path, USE.NAMES = FALSE),
  XML = sapply(img_urls, function(URL) XML::parseURI(URL)$path, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
) -> paths

glimpse(paths)
## Observations: 100
## Variables: 3
## $ urltools <chr> "vp/969b7087cc97408ccee167d473388761/5C55ABEB/t51.2885-15/e35/82359289_380972639303339_908467218_h...
## $ httr     <chr> "vp/969b7087cc97408ccee167d473388761/5C55ABEB/t51.2885-15/e35/82359289_380972639303339_908467218_h...
## $ XML      <chr> "/vp/969b7087cc97408ccee167d473388761/5C55ABEB/t51.2885-15/e35/82359289_380972639303339_908467218_...
```

Note the not really standard inclusion of the initial, `/` in the path from `XML`. That's not important for you for this example, but it's important to note the difference in general.

We'll process one of them since `XML` and `httr` have that woeful limitation:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  urltools = urltools::url_parse(img_urls[1])$path,
  httr = httr::parse_url(img_urls[1])$path,
  XML = XML::parseURI(img_urls[1])$path
)
## Unit: microseconds
##      expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq      max neval
##  urltools 351.268 397.6040 557.09641 499.2220 618.5945 1309.454   100
##      httr 550.298 619.5080 843.26520 717.0705 888.3915 4213.070   100
##       XML  11.858  16.9115  27.97848  26.1450  33.9065  109.882   100
```

`XML` *looks* faster, but it's not in practice:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  urltools = urltools::url_parse(img_urls)$path,
  httr = sapply(img_urls, function(URL) httr::parse_url(URL)$path, USE.NAMES = FALSE),
  XML = sapply(img_urls, function(URL) XML::parseURI(URL)$path, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
)
## Unit: microseconds
##      expr       min        lq      mean     median        uq        max neval
##  urltools   718.887   853.374  1093.404   918.3045  1146.540   2872.076   100
##      httr 58513.970 64738.477 80697.548 68908.7635 81549.154 224157.857   100
##       XML  1155.370  1245.415  2012.660  1359.8215  1880.372  26184.943   100
```

If you really want to go the regex route, you can read the RFC for the URL BNF and a naive regex for hacking bits out of one and Google for the seminal example that has over a dozen regular expressions that handle not-so-well-formed URIs, but parsing is generally a better strategy for diverse URL content. For your case, splitting and regex'ing might work just fine but it isn't necessarily going to be that much faster than parsing:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  urltools = tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(urltools::url_parse(img_urls)$path)),
  httr = tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(sapply(img_urls, function(URL) httr::parse_url(URL)$path, USE.NAMES = FALSE))),
  XML = tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(sapply(img_urls, function(URL) XML::parseURI(URL)$path, USE.NAMES = FALSE))),
  regex = stri_match_first_regex(img_urls, "/([[:digit:]]{8}_[[:digit:]]{15}_[[:digit:]]{9}_[[:alpha:]]{1})\\.jpg\\?")[,2]
)
## Unit: milliseconds
##      expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq        max neval
##  urltools  1.140421  1.228988  1.502525  1.286650  1.444522   6.970044   100
##      httr 56.563403 65.696242 77.492290 69.809393 80.075763 157.657508   100
##       XML  1.513174  1.604012  2.039502  1.702018  1.931468  11.306436   100
##     regex  1.137204  1.223683  1.337675  1.260339  1.397273   2.241121   100
```

As noted in that final example, you'll need to run `tools::file_path_sans_ext()` on the result to remove the `.jpg` (or `sub()` it away).

Answer (score 2):

This requires two things:

1. parse the URL itself
2. get the filename from the path of the URL

You can do both manually but it’s *much* better to use existing tools. The first part is solved by the `parseURI` function from the ‹XML› package:

```
uri = 'https://content_xxx.xxx.com/vp/969ffffff61/5C55ABEB/t51.2ff5-15/e35/13643048_612108275661958_805860992_n.jpg?ff_cache_key=fffffQ%3ff%3D.2
parts = XML::parseURI(uri)
```

And the second part is trivially solved by the `basename` function:

```
filename = basename(parts$path)
```

Comment: I agree Konrad's answer is a better way to do it, but just to present an alternative, you can do this using `regex` using the commands `uri <- "https://scontent-mxp1-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/969b7087cc97408ccee167d473388761/5C55ABEB/t51.2885-15/e35/13643048_612108275661958_805860992_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTMwOTE4NjEyMzc1OTAzOTc2NQ%3D%3D.2"
filename <- gsub("(^.*\\/)(.*\\.jpg)(.*$)", "\\2", uri)`

Comment: it still has the extension and isn't working on the vector of URIs